# Give read-only permissions but just to a single table in azure data explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'd like to give read-only access to a user but just on a single table.
According to this page, there is no role for that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/access-control/role-based-authorization

Is there any alternative to that?

Answer (score 2):

> *According to this page, there is no role for that*

Correct (as of January 2022).

> *Is there any alternative to that?*

Depending on the full set of requirements, you may be able to achieve your goal using either of the following policies:

- [Restricted view access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy)
- [Row level security policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy)

Comment: Another option (but a slightly costly one) is to create a follower cluster on the database, and configure it to follow only this table. Then you can grant Viewer access to that user to the followed database, with that single table.

Comment: I'll look into the restricted view, the follower cluster seems overkill. 
Thank you both.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Why do you not have TableViewer role? If I need SP1 to access Table1 only and SP2 access Table2 only, Restricted View Policy won't work. With Row Level Policy I need to work on OTHER tables to restrict them?

Comment: you can add/upvote feature requests @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice. for example: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a9f475e3-eb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0